# socket.io doesn't send message back to socket

Tags: node.js, reactjs, websocket, socket.io

i'm working on an app which communicate with server via socket.io,
users in my app have unique ids which i want to use on my server
so i made a small class which contains fields with these unique ids and a socket

```
import {Socket} from 'socket.io'

export interface VKClient{
    vkid: string,
    socket: Socket
}

export class VKClients{
    clients: VKClient[] = []

    addClient(client: VKClient){
        this.clients.push(client)
    }

    sendToClient(id: string, message: string, data?: any){
        this.clients.find(x => x.vkid === id)?.socket.emit(message)
    }
}
```

so in index.ts i have structure

```
const io = new Server(5000, {
    cors: {
        origin: '*'
    }
})

const clients = new VKClients()

io.on('connection', (client) => onConnect(client, clients))
```

and onConnect handler looks like

```
const onConnect = (client: Socket, clients: VKClients) => {
    client.on('handshake', (data: {uid: string, salt: string}) => {
        const newClient: VKClient = {vkid: data.uid, socket: client}
        clients.addClient(newClient)
        clients.sendToClient(data.uid, 'handshake')
    })
    client.on('getThemes', async (callback) => callback(await getThemes()))
}
```

the problem is when user on a client side sends handshake message nothing happens, the server receives this message, the data is normal, it has id and hash, the socket is added to my class, i can find him there via custom id, but i can't send message using sendToClient method, broadcast from socket.io and foreach works fine, and if i console.log structure inside sendToClient method it will log `true`
p.s. ids which are operated by socket.io in the class and in the onConnect handler are identical

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems like there is an issue in my logic of storing clients because when i replace `this...find(x => x.vkid === id)...` to `forEach(x => {if(x.vkid === id)...}` it works as expected